# Is it possible to generate an EF data model (edmx) from code first POCO classes?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, edmx, entity-framework-5

I like the Code First approach, but often I would prefer a visual model. The edmx model is  a lot friendlier and neater for modelling a 'data model' than VS class diagrams, so it would be nice to generate an edmx from the code first POCOs and start round trip engineering, seeing as  it is possible to generate POCOs from the edmx model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this vs extension to generate edmx diagram from code first dbContext, its read only as of now (extension is only in beta) http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a database from your POCOs, you can then add a new EF item to your project and  have it generate the model from the database. It's a little roundabout but it works well. I use it to check that the relations in code first models actually match what I intended.